# How to use itoa in C

Tags: c, itoa

Can anybody tell me how to use `itoa` function in C?

The prototype is:

```
char*itoa(int_Val,char*_DstBuf,int_Radix)
```

I think that `int_Val` is the value that I want to convert
`char*_DstBuf`, is the string where I want to store the result
But what is `int_Radix`?

Comment: I cannot say a lot more than this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: `itoa` is a non-standard function. Use `sprintf` or even `snprintf`, instead.

Comment: radix is base.example 10(base10) means 10 in base10 radix but equals to 12 in base8 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the base to convert to

10 - Decimal
16 - Hexidecimal
8 - Octal

A per the manual page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/